# How would I go about retrieving the `release_date`

Tags: javascript, node.js

How would I go about retrieving the `release_date` and then removing everything from that except the year, in the example it would be `2022`

*There is MULTIPLE results that would need this so... im clueless on how to approach this.*

##### Code:

```js
const endpoint = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${apikey}&language=en-US&page=1`;

const fetchMovies = (endpoint) => {
  fetch(endpoint)
    .then((result) => result.json())
    .then((result) => {
      console.log([...result.results]);
    });
};

fetchMovies(endpoint);
```

##### Example of output:

```json
[
  {
    adult: false,
    backdrop_path: '/8pgKccb5PfE1kWB9qqiXJem83VC.jpg',
    genre_ids: [ 28, 53 ],
    id: 522016,
    original_language: 'en',
    original_title: 'The 355',
    overview: 'A group of top female agents from American, British, Chinese, Columbian and German  government agencies are drawn together to try and stop an organization from acquiring a deadly weapon to send the world into chaos.',
    popularity: 1276.737,
    poster_path: '/uQt2dJFMnJmAp9zLAWNfGilK0BW.jpg',
    release_date: '2022-01-05',
    title: 'The 355',
    video: false,
    vote_average: 6.1,
    vote_count: 261
  }
]
```

Comment: On way you can do this is to `map` the data - have a read here about `Array.map()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: for getting just the year you can get substring of release date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const endpoint = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${apikey}&language=en-US&page=1`;

const fetchMovies = (endpoint) => {
  fetch(endpoint)
    .then((result) => result.json())
    .then((result) => {
      const res = result.results.map((movie) => {
        const releaseYear = movie.release_date.split("-")[0];
        return { ...movie, release_date: releaseYear }
      });
      console.log(res);
    });
};

fetchMovies(endpoint);
```

Notice that, I am using `map` to get the same number of results back while modifying the release_date. We can split the date string by "-" and get the first index to retrieve only year part.

Comment: Honestly, didn't think of using `map`, I've been wrecking my head for a few days with websockets and other stuff, so without thinking about it properly, you know staring at the code for hours and wait for the lightbulb... this however does fix the issue I was having.

Answer (score 1):

**Use [getFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear). If output = result.results then try this:**

```js
// output = result.results;
output = [
  {
    adult: false,
    backdrop_path: '/8pgKccb5PfE1kWB9qqiXJem83VC.jpg',
    genre_ids: [ 28, 53 ],
    id: 522016,
    original_language: 'en',
    original_title: 'The 355',
    overview: 'A group of top female agents from American, British, Chinese, Columbian and German  government agencies are drawn together to try and stop an organization from acquiring a deadly weapon to send the world into chaos.',
    popularity: 1276.737,
    poster_path: '/uQt2dJFMnJmAp9zLAWNfGilK0BW.jpg',
    release_date: '2022-01-05',
    title: 'The 355',
    video: false,
    vote_average: 6.1,
    vote_count: 261
  }
]

const res = output.map((movie) => {
    movie.release_date = new Date(movie.release_date).getFullYear();
    return movie;
});
console.log(res);
```